# Reading excel values in python from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, input, printing

I'm new to this community and I'm currently learning Python. For my first little project, I want to ask the user for input (An element from the periodic table) and print the corresponding properties such as name, number and mass.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'path\excelfile.xlsx')
    
Symbol = input('Input Symbol: ')

try:
    value = df.index[df['Symbol']== Symbol].tolist()[0]
    print(f'properties of {Symbol} are: ')
    print("Element Name: ",df['Atomic_name'][value])
    print("Element Number : ",df['Atomic_number'][value])
    print("Element Mass  : ",df['Atomic_weight'][value], "g/mol")
except IndexError:
    print('Symbol not found')
```

For the excel file, I'm using the following file: [https://easyupload.io/qrl7yu][1]

Frankly, it works for the first symbol only if your input is 'H' resulting in the following output:

```
Input Symbol: H
properties of H are:
Element Name  :  Hydrogen
Element Number:  1
Element Mass  :  1.01 g/mol
```

This is exactly what I want but when I try a symbol from the same column 'Symbol', it won't work. I want to have it work for all the symbols. How do I define that all the symbols for the input are from the same column? I think it has something to do with the 7th line where I define value =.

Wixxix
[1]: https://easyupload.io/qrl7yu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is working fine, the problem is with the symbols data containing extra spaces. You can use trim() function on excel first to clean the empty spaces and then retry your code.

For example you will see below the space between the quotes and Cr
That's causing a mismatch between your data and the input from the user
'   Cr'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('LoCE.xlsx')

user_input = input('Input Symbol: ')

mask = df.loc[:, 'Symbol'] == user_input

df_mask = df.loc[mask, :]

print(df_mask)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. The problem is that my input has to come from the same column (Symbols). For some reason, it only recognizes the first element of the column.

Comment: Your input comes from a user. OR (more likely) I don't know what you are trying to say ;-)

Comment: Excuse me, I have formulated it wrongly. What I wanted to say is if I run the code and it asks me to put in an element symbol e.g. (Mg). I want the code to recognize the symbol in the Symbol column of excel and thereafter print the corresponding properties. These properties are located in the same row. With my code, it only recognizes the first element (H) and no others. How do I define that Python has to search for the Symbol from the input in my symbol column?

Comment: Is it just the type of output of my excample that does not fit your requirements because if you enter a symbol in the program that I provided it returns exactly what you are looking for (the corresponding properties). I spared the nice format in my example with all the print statements and the input checker via try, but that could be added.

Comment: You are right! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Symbol column to str type,
then query using df.str.contains it works:

```
df['Symbol']=df['Symbol'].astype(str)
df[df['Symbol'].str.contains("Li")]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However, I don't want to print all the column headers, I only want to print the information from the columns.